# Sort JSON array by a property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

So,

This is a very simplified version of my JSON data:

```
 [
  {
    "category": "Financial",
    "item": "DIAS"
  },
  {
    "category": "Social",
    "item": "Andrew Barnett Explains..."
  },
  {
    "category": "Financial",
    "item": "FP Sales"
  }
]
```

and I want to arrange it like the following:

```
[
  {
    "category": "Financial",
    "items": [
      {
        "item": "DIAS"
      },
      {
        "item": "FP Sales"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Social",
    "items": [
      {
        "item": "Andrew Barnett Explains..."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What is the best way (performance wise) to achieve this? I am sure there is a better way than using two loops?

Thanks

Comment: Try to build something like `{"Financial":["DIAS", "FP Sales"], "Social": ["Andrew Barnett Explains", …], …}` as an intermediate result.

Comment: Are you asking about performance, or are you asking how to do it? What's the problem with two loops?

Comment: I am asking how to do this in the best possible way.

Comment: Why is the JSON data you are getting not in this format to start? Seems weird to reprocess something that has been processed once.

Comment: This is generated from a Joomla component which I am not allowed to modify the view (JSON view) of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put together a fiddle of something that works: http://jsfiddle.net/Hnj2s/

```
var temp =  [
  {
    "category": "Financial",
    "item": "DIAS"
  },
  {
    "category": "Social",
    "item": "Andrew Barnett Explains..."
  },
  {
    "category": "Financial",
    "item": "FP Sales"
  }
];

var output = [];
var lookup = {};
for(var i=0; i<temp.length; i+=1){
    var cat = temp[i].category;
    if(!lookup[cat]){
        lookup[cat] = {
            category: cat,
            items: []   
        };
        output.push(lookup[cat]);           
    }
    lookup[cat].items.push({
        item: temp[i].item
    });
}

console.log(output);
```

I'm not sure how you define *best possible way* here, and you might need to be specific. However this method works with a single loop through the items.

Comment: Thanks. Learnt something here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
  {
    "category": "Financial",
    "item": "DIAS"
  },
  {
    "category": "Social",
    "item": "Andrew Barnett Explains..."
  },
  {
    "category": "Financial",
    "item": "FP Sales"
  }
];
var newData = {};
var res = new Array();
$(data).each(function() {
    var cat = this.category;
    if (newData[cat] === undefined) {
        newData[cat]={};
        newData[cat].category = cat;
        newData[cat].Items = [{"Item": this.item}];
        res.push(newData[cat]);
    }
    else {
        newData[cat].Items.push({"Item": this.item});
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/dPhg7/

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore method

```
 _.groupBy
```

you can do it in this way:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/setec/vtXsL/20/)