# How to merge JSON Objects having same name

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

Initially I had Json Array which is array of array objects using `underscore` `groupBy` function , I have grouped and each are grouped but again I wanted to merge all the arrays which is having same object name , Below is the way I wanted to implement ,Can someone help me on this.

i.e. I have same JSON objects having same `versionId` in JSON array and now I wanted to merge all the JSON object which are having same `versionId`

Can someone help it can be done easily using `underscore` or `Lodash` frameworks

**Input JSON**

```
[
  {
    "21289": [
      {
        "id": 255463,
        "orderId": 226433,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person A",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person A",
        "cycleId": 4042,
        "cycleName": "Cycle A",
        "versionId": 21289,
        "versionName": "Version A",
        "issueKey": "A"
      },
      {
        "id": 255433,
        "orderId": 226403,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person B",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
        "cycleId": 4041,
        "cycleName": "Cycle B",
        "versionId": 21289,
        "versionName": "Version A",
        "issueKey": "B"
      },
      {
        "id": 255432,
        "orderId": 226402,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person B",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
        "cycleId": 4041,
        "cycleName": "Cycle B",
        "versionId": 21289,
        "versionName": "Version A",
        "issueKey": "C"
      }
    ],
    "21291": [
      {
        "id": 252067,
        "orderId": 223258,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "12/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person C",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person C",
        "cycleId": 3985,
        "cycleName": "Cycle C",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "D"
      },
      {
        "id": 252014,
        "orderId": 223205,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "12/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person C",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person C",
        "cycleId": 3985,
        "cycleName": "Cycle C",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "E"
      },
      {
        "id": 252012,
        "orderId": 223203,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "11/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person D",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person D",
        "cycleId": 3985,
        "cycleName": "Cycle C",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "F"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "21291": [
      {
        "id": 251449,
        "orderId": 222640,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "31/Aug/17",
        "executedBy": "Person E",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person E",
        "cycleId": 3978,
        "cycleName": "Cycle D",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "G"
      },
      {
        "id": 251299,
        "orderId": 222490,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "1/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person F",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person F",
        "cycleId": 3977,
        "cycleName": "Cycle E",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "H"
      }
    ],
    "31457": [
      {
        "id": 250969,
        "orderId": 222160,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "29/Aug/17",
        "executedBy": "Person G",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person G",
        "cycleId": 3973,
        "cycleName": "Cycle F",
        "versionId": 31457,
        "versionName": "Version C",
        "issueKey": "I"
      },
      {
        "id": 250871,
        "orderId": 222062,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "31/Aug/17",
        "executedBy": "Person D",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person D",
        "cycleId": 3973,
        "cycleName": "Cycle F",
        "versionId": 31457,
        "versionName": "Version C",
        "issueKey": "J"
      },
      {
        "id": 250869,
        "orderId": 222060,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "4/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person H",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person H",
        "cycleId": 3973,
        "cycleName": "Cycle F",
        "versionId": 31457,
        "versionName": "Version C",
        "issueKey": "K"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output JSON as I wanted**

```
[
  {
    "21289": [
      {
        "id": 255463,
        "orderId": 226433,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person A",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person A",
        "cycleId": 4042,
        "cycleName": "Cycle A",
        "versionId": 21289,
        "versionName": "Version A",
        "issueKey": "A"
      },
      {
        "id": 255433,
        "orderId": 226403,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person B",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
        "cycleId": 4041,
        "cycleName": "Cycle B",
        "versionId": 21289,
        "versionName": "Version A",
        "issueKey": "B"
      },
      {
        "id": 255432,
        "orderId": 226402,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person B",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
        "cycleId": 4041,
        "cycleName": "Cycle B",
        "versionId": 21289,
        "versionName": "Version A",
        "issueKey": "C"
      }
    ],
    "21291": [
      {
        "id": 252067,
        "orderId": 223258,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "12/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person C",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person C",
        "cycleId": 3985,
        "cycleName": "Cycle C",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "D"
      },
      {
        "id": 252014,
        "orderId": 223205,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "12/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person C",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person C",
        "cycleId": 3985,
        "cycleName": "Cycle C",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "E"
      },
      {
        "id": 252012,
        "orderId": 223203,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "11/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person D",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person D",
        "cycleId": 3985,
        "cycleName": "Cycle C",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "F"
      },
      {
        "id": 251449,
        "orderId": 222640,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "31/Aug/17",
        "executedBy": "Person E",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person E",
        "cycleId": 3978,
        "cycleName": "Cycle D",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "G"
      },
      {
        "id": 251299,
        "orderId": 222490,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "1/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person F",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person F",
        "cycleId": 3977,
        "cycleName": "Cycle E",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "H"
      }
    ],
    "31457": [
      {
        "id": 250969,
        "orderId": 222160,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "29/Aug/17",
        "executedBy": "Person G",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person G",
        "cycleId": 3973,
        "cycleName": "Cycle F",
        "versionId": 31457,
        "versionName": "Version C",
        "issueKey": "I"
      },
      {
        "id": 250871,
        "orderId": 222062,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "31/Aug/17",
        "executedBy": "Person D",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person D",
        "cycleId": 3973,
        "cycleName": "Cycle F",
        "versionId": 31457,
        "versionName": "Version C",
        "issueKey": "J"
      },
      {
        "id": 250869,
        "orderId": 222060,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "4/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person H",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person H",
        "cycleId": 3973,
        "cycleName": "Cycle F",
        "versionId": 31457,
        "versionName": "Version C",
        "issueKey": "K"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort JSON array by a property in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883584/sort-json-array-by-a-property-in-javascript)

Comment: No I have gone through these questions, those are not helping. Here I have arrays and I need to merge by considering all the arrays

Comment: @Batman The output json and input json you have posted are identical..

Comment: output json and input json seems the same...

Comment: Sorry all my bad that was copy paste mistake , Now I have update the Input and output Json Properly Thanks!!

Comment: No that does not work in my case.

Comment: "now I wanted to merge all the JSON object which are having same versionId" - I still don't see evidence of this in your output, unless I am misunderstanding. Usually "merge" means combine everything in that array of objects into one object, usually favoring properties from the last object merged.

Comment: @Damon , If you in my input ObjectName with `21291` is present in 2 different arrays and in output its merged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that structure will be exactly like this, here is quite simple solution:

```js
var a = [
  {
    "21289": [
      {
        "id": 255463,
        "orderId": 226433,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person A",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person A",
        "cycleId": 4042,
        "cycleName": "Cycle A",
        "versionId": 21289,
        "versionName": "Version A",
        "issueKey": "A"
      },
      {
        "id": 255433,
        "orderId": 226403,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person B",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
        "cycleId": 4041,
        "cycleName": "Cycle B",
        "versionId": 21289,
        "versionName": "Version A",
        "issueKey": "B"
      },
      {
        "id": 255432,
        "orderId": 226402,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person B",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
        "cycleId": 4041,
        "cycleName": "Cycle B",
        "versionId": 21289,
        "versionName": "Version A",
        "issueKey": "C"
      }
    ],
    "21291": [
      {
        "id": 252067,
        "orderId": 223258,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "12/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person C",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person C",
        "cycleId": 3985,
        "cycleName": "Cycle C",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "D"
      },
      {
        "id": 252014,
        "orderId": 223205,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "12/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person C",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person C",
        "cycleId": 3985,
        "cycleName": "Cycle C",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "E"
      },
      {
        "id": 252012,
        "orderId": 223203,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "11/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person D",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person D",
        "cycleId": 3985,
        "cycleName": "Cycle C",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "F"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "21291": [
      {
        "id": 251449,
        "orderId": 222640,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "31/Aug/17",
        "executedBy": "Person E",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person E",
        "cycleId": 3978,
        "cycleName": "Cycle D",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "G"
      },
      {
        "id": 251299,
        "orderId": 222490,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "1/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person F",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person F",
        "cycleId": 3977,
        "cycleName": "Cycle E",
        "versionId": 21291,
        "versionName": "Version B",
        "issueKey": "H"
      }
    ],
    "31457": [
      {
        "id": 250969,
        "orderId": 222160,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "29/Aug/17",
        "executedBy": "Person G",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person G",
        "cycleId": 3973,
        "cycleName": "Cycle F",
        "versionId": 31457,
        "versionName": "Version C",
        "issueKey": "I"
      },
      {
        "id": 250871,
        "orderId": 222062,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "31/Aug/17",
        "executedBy": "Person D",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person D",
        "cycleId": 3973,
        "cycleName": "Cycle F",
        "versionId": 31457,
        "versionName": "Version C",
        "issueKey": "J"
      },
      {
        "id": 250869,
        "orderId": 222060,
        "status": 1,
        "executedOn": "4/Sep/17",
        "executedBy": "Person H",
        "executedByDisplay": "Person H",
        "cycleId": 3973,
        "cycleName": "Cycle F",
        "versionId": 31457,
        "versionName": "Version C",
        "issueKey": "K"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function filterKeys(result, obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
   result[key] = (key in result? result[key].concat(obj[key]) : obj[key]);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(a.reduce(filterKeys, {}));
```